# Helper method takes to much time to retrieve data from Firebase causing rendering error

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Loading the state fail because the data to be displayed hasn't loaded yet.

At first, I put the server logic inside of my component and it worked, but I will need to re-use this on lots of components, so I decided to put my `readUserDate` function in a helper method, but now, it doesn't work anymore.

How can I fix this? (thank you in advance)

```
import config from "./Config"
import firebase from "firebase";

export function readUserData(path) {
    firebase.database().ref(path).on('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        return snapshot.val()
    });
}
```

```
import { readUserData } from "../../../server/Actions"
class Resultats extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        let path = "devInc"
        this.setState({
            results: readUserData(path),
            loading: false,
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>data</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.results['-LbstaCmVt1nAWUrTw4T'].date}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const readUserData = async() => {
    const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref(path).on('value');
    return snapshot.val();
};

import { readUserData } from "../../../server/Actions"
class Resultats extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            results: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.readData();
    }

    readData = async() => {
        let path = "devInc";
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        const results = await readUserData(path);

        this.setState({ loading: false, results });
    };

    render() {
        const { loading, results } = this.state;


        if (loading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                </View>
            );
        }
        if (!results) return null;

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>data</Text>
                <Text>{results['-LbstaCmVt1nAWUrTw4T'].date}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

**Suggestion**

This could be better done that through redux action

Comment: still not working, nothing is render because the data arrives to late (i'v checked with console.log(snapshot.val())